# Resolution of a scintillator

Tags: particle-detectors

I am thinking on buying a scintillator for a particle physics lab lesson. I would like to know what is the best way of measuring its resolution (the photon yield is 4$\times10^4$ photons/MeV and I'm measuring ~MeV particles) and if this will be dependent on the detector used

Comment: Detector manufacturers usually publish full-width at half-maximum (FWHM) data for specific scintillator/PM combinations. The PM is going to play a significant part in determining the resolution, along with the specific scintillator material. The photon count uncertainty will be $\sqrt{N}$, or about 200/MeV for your number. Then the electronics will add a bit of spread to that.

Comment: The simplest electronics for this is to use the soundcard input of a computer and to do the analysis in software. See  http://www.prutchi.com/2012/02/20/new-radiation-detection-related-posts-at-www-diyphysics-com/ and gammaspectacular.com

Comment: what about a Ge detector and a scope? wouldn't that give the best energy resolution?